# Concatenate two data-frames and save unique value as txt

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

this is my first post I was looking for some help.

I have 2 large csv files that share some unique values and I have written a small python script to help extract the unique fields and save them to sub-directories. The problem I'm having is that I would like to save the extracted values to the parent folder as  extracted.txt file.

```py
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import os
import json


large = pd.read_csv('large.csv')
medium = pd.read_csv('medium.csv')

#Grouped and split our dataframes by 'Distance & Diameter'
split1_groups = large.groupby('Distance')
split2_groups = medium.groupby('Diameter')

#loop through the groups and save to directories based on unique values
for name, group in split1_groups:
  if not os.path.exists(name):
    os.mkdir(name)
  group.to_csv(name + "/large.csv", index=0)

for name, group in split2_groups:
  if not os.path.exists(name):
    os.mkdir(name)
  group.to_csv(name + "/medium.csv", index=0)
```

After I loop through the groups how I save the extracted values to a .txt & with the the new sub-directory folder name set to "extracted"?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to extract unique Distance and Diameter values from the two dataframes and save them to .txt files?

You can obtain unique values from a column in a dataframe by using the `.unique()` method:

```
unique_dist_vls = large.Distance.unique()
unique_diam_vls = medium.Diameter.unique()
```

Then you can use this to save each array to a .txt file (each unique value will be printed on separate line in the file):

```
import os
os.makedirs("extracted")

with open("./extracted/extracted.txt", "w") as txt_file:
   print("\n".join(unique_dist_vls), file=txt_file)
```

If this does not fully address your question, please clarify what your expected output is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AlexK
I'm trying to save the values from split_groups1 & split_groups2 to a txt file. With the parent directory folder called "extracted".
I think instead of an array I need a list in ascending order.

Comment: @Kamz Which values? Values of Distance and Diameter (like I show) or something else?  Array and list accomplish the same thing. And in my answer the result is printed in ascending order.